# If else operator with short way

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have if else operators with statement

```
$row["column"] = ($example == "H") ? "first" : "second";
```

I need to add `else if` condition to this. Need to write something like code bellow but with `?` and `:`. Looking for shorter code way, is it possible?

```
if($example == "H")
{
  $example = "first";
}
else if($example == "K")
{
  $example = "smth different";
}
else if($example == "X")
{
  $example =" third one";
}
else
{
  $example = "go away";
{
```

Comment: Chaining ternary operators is a bad idea. It quickly gets hard to read. What about a  `switch`?

Comment: Yeah `switch` is the perfect use case here

Comment: *"I have if else statement"* -- "`?:`" is not a statement, it is an operator. Operators and statements are different things, with different purposes in life. They cannot be interchanged.

Comment: [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: i know switch way, but i am more interesting in `? : ` way)

Comment: @axiac thank you, i fixed that.

Comment: There is no such thing like *"if else operator"*. ["`if`"](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) (with or without "`else`") is a control structure (i.e. statement), [`?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is the ternary conditional operator. Operators connect subexpressions to generate larger expressions. Expressions are evaluated, they have value. The control structures do not have value. They control what code is executed. Different things for different purposes.

Comment: [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is probably the best for you here. Don't forget the `break`s.

Comment: I see that if i have many if else operators it is useless to use `? :` best way is switch. Thanks for all !)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chaining ternary operators isn't a good idea. Shorter code doesn't always mean its more readable! If you use multiple ternary operators inside one another, it very quickly becomes unreadable.

Instead, use a `switch` that checks for each case.

```
switch ($example) {
    case "H":
        $example = "first";
        break;
    case "K":
        $example = "smth different";
        break;
    case "X":
        $example =" third one";
        break;
    default:
        $example = "go away";
}
```

- [PHP controlstructure: `switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: I see that if i have many if else operators it is useless to use `? :` best way is switch. Thanks!)

Answer (score 5):

Use an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$map = [
  'H' => 'first',
  'K' => 'smth different',
  'X' => 'third one',
];

$val = 'go away';
if (isset($map[$example])) {
  $val = $map[$example];
}

echo $val;
```

Or use a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch ($example) {
  case 'H':
    $val = 'first';
    break;
  case 'K':
    $val = 'smth different';
    break;
  case 'X':
    $val = 'third one';
    break;
  default:
    $val = 'go away';
    break;
}

echo $val;
```

Comment: I see that if i have many if else operators it is useless to use `? :` best way is switch. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch statement instead of an if/else, example:

```
switch ($example)
{
    case 'A':
        $example = 'first';
        break;
    case 'B':
        $example = 'second';
        break;
    default:
        $example = 'default';
}
```

Comment: I see that if i have many if else operators it is useless to use `? :` best way is switch. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

you can just nest them:

```
$row["column"] = ($example == "H") ? "first" : $row["column"] = ($example == "K") ? "smth different" : ...;
```

also I would recommend using switch not this

Comment: That won't work either, because you need to group the condition as you go deeper.

Comment: I see that if i have many if else operators it is useless to use `? :` best way is switch. Thanks!)